# Only apply changes to table inside unknown boundaries (walls)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I want my loop to only change the table cell from 0 to 5 inside the "walls".
The "walls" are user defined and could be of any shape, based on coordinates.
The plot is only for visualization.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd

wallPointsX = [5,5,30,30,55,55,5]
wallPointsY = [5,30,30,55,55,5,5]

df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=range(60), columns=range(60))

for x in range(0, 60):
    for y in range(0, 60):
        df[x][y] = 5 #Should only apply inside "walls"

plt.plot(wallPointsX, wallPointsY)
plt.pcolor(df)
plt.show()
```

[Result plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbXTE.png)

Comment: you want to fill all those values with something?

Comment: Yes, the loop is dumbed down, but I want to give every cell inside the "walls" a value. In this case 5. Every cell outside the wall should remain unchanged, as value 0.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, took me some time but it was fun doing it. The idea here is to first create a continuous `path` out of the coordinates which define the walls. Next, create an object `Path`. Now you loop through each point in the DataFrame and then look if the created `Path` contains that (x,y) point using `contains_point`. I additionally had to use the condition `x==55 and (5<y<=55)` in the `if` statement so as to include the column adjacent to the 
right most wall.

```
import matplotlib.path as mplPath
import numpy as np

wallPointsX = [5,5,30,30,55,55,5]
wallPointsY = [5,30,30,55,55,5,5]

# Create a continuous path across the wall coordinates
path = np.array([list(i) for i in zip(wallPointsX, wallPointsY)])
Path = mplPath.Path(path)

df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=range(60), columns=range(60))

for x in range(0, 60):
    for y in range(0, 60):
        if Path.contains_point((x,y)) or (x==55 and (5<y<=55)):
            df[x-1][y-1] = 5 #Should only apply inside "walls"

plt.plot(wallPointsX, wallPointsY)
plt.pcolor(df)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! But it still needs to be more dynamic in terms of user input (path).                                                                                                                     
For example, try this path: wallPointsX = [5,5,30,30,55,55,30,30,20,20,5]
wallPointsY = [5,55,55,30,30,5,5,20,20,5,5]

Comment: Yes, as you can see after applying the above solution to the new walls, the portions which are left are always on the right hand side. Apparently `contains_point` doesn't include the points on the edges. Look [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9704). Perhaps you can add some if statements to het things done for your particular case.